# How to build a query string with mysql-simpl?

Tags: haskell

I know that the Query type exists to make code injection difficult. But I need to call "describe tablename" and substitute the table name with the table I want to describe.

Since I'm fairly new to Haskell I have no idea how to accomplish this.

So far the code looks like this:

```
describe :: String -> SqlQuery [FieldInfo]
describe table = sqlQuery_ "describe " ++ table
```

But that results in

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fromString to transform a string to a query

```
 SqlQuery_ . fromString $ "describe" ++ table
```

( not tested, I am answering from my phone)

Comment: This gives:  Not in scope: ‘fromString’

Comment: And what does . fromString really do ?

Comment: formatting convert a string to a query. The dot is just compose the two functions